# I am dealing with my web service while getting response -how to get response from server side?

Tags: android, web-services, post, httpclient

I have used post method to call web service and getting an error while calling the web service .

Logcat:

```
09-04 04:58:56.437: E/AndroidRuntime(803): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-04 04:58:56.437: E/AndroidRuntime(803): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occure while executing doInBackground()
```

the web service i am using is
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask {

```
     /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         String username = user.getText().toString();
         String password = pass.getText().toString();
        super.onPreExecute(); 

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Loginpage.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag
        String username=args [0];
        String password=args[1];
        int success;

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(Loginpage.this, Propertyapp.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;            
    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Loginpage.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

---

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List params) {

```
    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String username = user.getText().toString();` move this line in onPreExecute method ..u cannot handle Ui in doInBackground Method

Comment: when i changed this i am  getting error in doinbackground with this statement  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

Comment: actually my point is u should do the ui related initialization in onPreexecute meyhod

Comment: yes u should declare in class that variable so that do in background method has access to that avriable

Comment: after declaring the method u said in class i am getting this error     09-04 05:14:13.167: E/AndroidRuntime(999): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vinnipostpropertyapp/com.example.vinnipostpropertyapp.Loginpage}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: yes since ur variable is null it does not contain anything.. did u put user.getText.tioString(); line in preexecute method?

Comment: i declared this globally before oncreate() method

Comment: when i am putting this line in preexecute() method i am getting an error in these two lines     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

Answer (score 0):

I think the lines
`String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();` cause the problem.

You can't access or modify UI inside AsyncTask.

You can do this before it either inside onPreExecute()
(Prefer to declare variables globally)

or before calling `.execute("")` and passing username and password as args ie, `.execute(username,password);`. Then inside doInBackground, you can get it as args[0] and args[1].

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this might help you.
 int sucess;//declare in global
 @Override

 protected String doInBackground(String... args)
   {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     // Check for success tag

     String username = user.getText().toString();
     String password = pass.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        // getting product details by making HTTP request
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
               LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
        try
        {
        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    pDialog.dismiss();//progress dialog pDialog
        if (success == 1) {    
            Intent i = new Intent(Loginpage.this, Propertyapp.class);
            startActivity(i);
           finish();
        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare intent globally & initialize in oncreate(),

```
Intent i ;

i= new Intent(Loginpage.this, Propertyapp.class);
```

use it as per your requirement

```
            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem

```
String username = user.getText().toString();
String password = pass.getText().toString();
```

You can not perform UI updates in the background thread. Move them out.
You can use onPreExecute() method for that, or just pass username and password to the AsyncTask().

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String username = params[0];
            String password = params[1];
                         ....
         }
}
```

Comment: yes 09-05 10:07:03.257: E/AndroidRuntime(18239): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-05 10:07:03.257: E/AndroidRuntime(18239): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-05 10:07:03.257: E/AndroidRuntime(18239):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-05 10:07:03.257: E/AndroidRuntime(18239):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352) after pressing the button i want to login and show another respective page

Comment: try to move startActivity(i); in the onPostExecute() method!

Comment: on adding mu username an d password when i am clicking login button i am getting this error     09-05 10:35:15.817: E/WindowManager(21519): Activity com.example.vinnipostpropertyapp.Loginpage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d3f0d8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-228,72} that was originally added here
09-05 10:35:15.817: E/WindowManager(21519): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.vinnipostpropertyapp.Loginpage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d3f0d8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-228,72}